# Scala - Convert TrieMap to HashMap

Tags: scala, hashmap

I am using a using a [TrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap) on which I perform a .mapValues() operation which returns a MapLike[] object.But I need to convert it into HashMap, or any Serializable Map that maintains sort order, because it have to transfer over the network. What is the most performance efficient way to do this?

Comment: `yourTrieMap.toMap`?

Comment: TrieMap is Serializable, and HashMap doesn't maintains order. I don't really get your question

Comment: As maps don't maintain order, you could start with `.toSeq` and see if it can meet your needs? Perhaps SortedMap if necessary?

Comment: @kosii, my bad. Just edited the question to explain the use case further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.mapValues` doesn't actually create a new `TrieMap`, it just returns a view of the original. To actually transform and create a new `TrieMap` out of your old collection, you could use the `.transform` method with a slightly different signature, which returns a new collection of the same type. The only drawback is that you have to use the same value type:

```
scala> val map = TrieMap(1->5).transform((k, v) => v + 1)
map: scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Int,Int] = TrieMap(1 -> 6)

scala> :t map
scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[Int,Int]
```